# RegExp for Phone Number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use `RegExp()` to accept the following inputs:

- 1234567890
- 12 34 56 78 90
- 12-34-56-78-90
- 12.34.56.78.90
- 12 34.56-7890

What I have been trying to use is:

```
([0-9]{2,2}[ |-|.]?){4,4}[0-9]{2,2}
```

Which I understand as: (digit 2 times, followed by space or - or . or nothing) 4 times, then digit 2 times.

I have been testing `[0-9]{2,2}` which doesn't even behave as I expected since it accepts **at least** 2 digits, and not **exactly** 2 digits.

Comment: Use anchors, `^` and `$`. `{2,2}` = `{2}`. And `[ |-|.]` should be written as `[ .-]`.

Comment: Can you describe what patter should match and what not? Maybe it's easier to remove all non-numeric values and than check length/area code at beginning?

Comment: `|`s in a character classes aren't `or`s they are the literal character. The `-` makes a range.

Comment: @chris85 The `-` makes a range, only when in a char class, but not at the very beginning nor at the very end of the class.

Comment: @sp00m `|-|` is in the middle. (it is a 1 character range in this instance but not what the OP meant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should suit your needs (last case not matched as expected):

```
^\d{2}([ .-]?)\d{2}(?:\1\d{2}){3}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vQFf60/2)

Comment: this is great, thx for make me discover regex101.com ! However it doesn't work in var exp = new RegExp("..."); exp.test(mystring). I know this has nothing to do with the expression, but my use of RegExp. Any hint?

Comment: If you use `new RegExp("...");`, you need to escape all the backslashes: `^\\d{2}([ .-]?)\\d{2}(?:\\1\\d{2}){3}$`. Better use `/^\d{2}([ .-]?)\d{2}(?:\1\d{2}){3}$/.test(mystring)` directly. See https://jsfiddle.net/sp00m/rvmzyfc0/.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var mob=/^([0-9]{2}(\s|\.|\-)){4}[0-9]{2}$/;
console.log(mob.test("12.34.56.78.90"));
console.log(mob.test("12-34-56-78-90"));
console.log(mob.test("12 34 56 78 90"));
```

```js
var mob=/^([0-9]{2}(\s|\.|\-)?){4}[0-9]{2}$/;
console.log(mob.test("1234567890"));
console.log(mob.test("12 34 56 78 90"));
```

Comment: `(\s|\.|\-)` can be rewritten `[\s.-]`; `\s` includes tab, form feed and line feed, not sure should be allowed; `[0-9]` can be rewritten `\d`.